# git alias not receiving parameters

Tags: linux, git, github, parameters, alias

I've been trying to create a new alias that send files to staging area, and at the same time it commit with a message.
I've tried this:

```
git config --global alias.stagecomm '!git add -A && git commit -m $1'
```

When I try to run:

```
git stagecomm "Commit"
```

It says that it didn't match any files known to git.

Answer (score 0):

Try with a `sh`: edit your `git config --global --edit` and type:

```
 !sh -c 'git add -A && git commit -m $1'
```

---

Another option: define a script (even on Windows) without extension, called `git-stagecomm`

In it, put your commands:

```
git add -A
git commit -m $1
```

If that script is in your path, you will be able to call it with `git stagecomm "mymessage"`

Any script called `git-xxx` will be executed by the git bash, as `git xxx`.
No alias needed there.

---

That being said, you could also type (without alias)

```
git commit -am "My message"
```

See [`git commit` man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit).

```
-a
--all
```

> Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been modified and deleted, but new files you have not told Git about are not affected.

That would not take *new* files though.